# How can I obtain data such as name, ID, address, of the oldest contact of an account in case I have more than 1 contact?

Tags: query, account, contact

Part of a requirement is to send the account contact details, but in case you have more than one contact you should take the oldest one ... How could you achieve this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It rather depends on just what you mean by "oldest contact". If you mean the contact that was first created, that's easy since there's the `CreatedDate` on all objects including `Contact`. If you mean the first one added to the `Account`, that's harder to do. You would have to add some data to track when a Contact is added to an Account (i.e. when the Account relationship changes). Then you can use that in your ORDER BY in a sub-query like Derek F mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to do some processing via Apex, or you could make use of a parent-child subquery.

A parent-child subquery is a query inside of a query. It looks something like this:

```
// 'Opportunities' is the child relationship name
// Typically just the plural of the object name (and using __r instead of __c for custom objects)
//   but you may have to look that information up (one way is by going to the relationship
//   field on the child object).
[SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name, Amount FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :ids]
```

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses in the subquery. Putting all that together makes it possible to fetch a single contact (oldest, newest, some other criteria, etc...)

Comment: Thank you so much Derek! :)